# Passing path from batch file to mysql

Tags: mysql, batch-file

**My batch file will contain some thing like this :**

```
set MUSER=root
set MPASS=xprd123
set MHOST=172.33.49.55
set DB=DBName1
set MBIN=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin

set scriptpath=D:/Graph_draw/ASSET_Creation/EXTERNAL/MYSQL_STATS_COLLECTOR/foldrname1
"%MBIN%\mysql.exe" -u"%MUSER%" -p"%MPASS%" -h "%MHOST%" "%DB%" -e "set @2:='%scriptpath%'; source DBQuery1.sql;"
```

**Content of DBQuery1.sql will be :**

```
SELECT 'INNODB_OS_LOG_WRITTEN','QUESTIONS'
UNION
select MAX(IF(variable_name = 'INNODB_OS_LOG_WRITTEN', VARIABLE_VALUE, NULL)) 
AS INNODB_OS_LOG_WRITTEN, MAX(IF(variable_name = 'QUESTIONS', VARIABLE_VALUE, NULL)) 
AS QUESTIONS from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS INTO OUTFILE '@2/Stats.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

I am not sure this is the way to pass path to the SELECT query inside DBQuery1.sql.

This code is not working.

ERROR I am getting is :

```
ERROR 1 (HY000) at line 1 in file: 'DBQuery1.sql': Can't create/write to file 'C
:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\Data\
@2\Stats.csv' (Errcode: 2)
```

I looked at other posts on passing path to batch file, but whatever I tried, I am not able to solve this issue.

When I execute the batch file, I am not sure if the path is getting passed into the sql file and if yes, why @2 is not getting the path passed.

Could anybody kindly help on this.

**UPDATE :**

To add to the details I have given above, I found that the path passed is received in the sql file.

I printed the variable output like this :

```
**SELECT @2;**
SELECT 'INNODB_OS_LOG_WRITTEN','QUESTIONS' 
UNION 
select MAX(IF(variable_name = 'INNODB_OS_LOG_WRITTEN', VARIABLE_VALUE, NULL)) AS INNODB_OS_LOG_WRITTEN, 

MAX(IF(variable_name = 'QUESTIONS', VARIABLE_VALUE, NULL)) AS QUESTIONS 
from information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS  
INTO OUTFILE '@2\Stats.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The output I got is :

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| @2                                                                     |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| D:/Graph_draw/ASSET_Creation/EXTERNAL/MYSQL_STATS_COLLECTOR/foldrname1 |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------+
ERROR 1 (HY000) at line 2 in file: 'DBQuery1.sql': Can't create/write to file 'C
:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\Data\
@2\Stats.csv' (Errcode: 2)
```

This means that @2 is not getting the value in '@2\Stats.csv', but SELECT @2; in the sql is getting the value.

Any help?

Comment: try using \\ instead of \ in the path, or use / instead of \.

Comment: It seems this is a bug in MySQL.Path value passed into an sql file for 'OUTFILE '@2\Stats.csv', does not get substituted in @2.

Comment: Ah I see what you mean. Well it sure is inconvenient but it is not a bug. The documentation clearly states that it should be a filename, not a string value. There is a feature request for this http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=13870 although I doubt it will ever be picked up.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, as you yourself pointed out, that the user-defined variable @2 is not expanded to its value in the file specification of INTO OUTFILE. 
There is a way around that, using dynamic SQL:

```
SET @stmt = CONCAT(
    ' SELECT ''INNODB_OS_LOG_WRITTEN'',''QUESTIONS'''
,   ' UNION'
,   ' SELECT MAX(IF(variable_name = ''INNODB_OS_LOG_WRITTEN'', VARIABLE_VALUE, NULL)) AS INNODB_OS_LOG_WRITTEN'
,   ' ,      MAX(IF(variable_name = ''QUESTIONS'', VARIABLE_VALUE, NULL)) AS QUESTIONS'
,   ' FROM information_schema.GLOBAL_STATUS'
,   ' INTO OUTFILE ', @2, '/Stats.csv'
,   ' FIELDS TERMINATED BY '','''
,   ' ENCLOSED BY ''"'''
,   ' LINES TERMINATED BY ''\n'''
);
PREPARE stmt FROM @stmt;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```